# nav bar center tailwind

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I would like to center the navbar but I don't know how I can do that.

I am using tailwind, can we use flexbox and grid at the same time

```html
    <h1 class="text-3xl text-center">Epicery</h1>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-4 flex">
        <div class="w-full text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800 items-center">
            <div x-data="{ open: false }" class="flex flex-col max-w-screen-xl px-4 mx-auto md:items-center md:justify-between md:flex-row md:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <nav :class="{'flex': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-col flex-grow pb-4 md:pb-0 hidden md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row">
                    <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-gray-700 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">About</a>
                    <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Contact</a>
                    <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                        <button @click="open = !open" class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span>Dropdown</span>
                            <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg md:w-48">
                            <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
                                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #1</a>
                                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #2</a>
                                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #3</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
<h1 class="text-3xl text-center">Epicery</h1>
<div class="flex">
    <div class="text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800 mx-auto">
        <div x-data="{ open: false }" class="flex flex-col max-w-screen-xl px-4 mx-auto md:items-center md:justify-between md:flex-row md:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <nav :class="{'flex': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-col flex-grow pb-4 md:pb-0 hidden md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row">
                <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-gray-700 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Blog</a>
                <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Contact</a>
                <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                    <button @click="open = !open" class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                        <span>Dropdown</span>
                        <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg md:w-48">
                        <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
                            <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #1</a>
                            <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #2</a>
                            <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my opinion, your definition is overloaded with css. In the beginning I would building my layout with the CSS Grid Model only. Then use the Flex Model within the grid to design. And only install media queries at the end.